# Spotify API authorization works with cURL but not with python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, httprequest, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get an acess token from the Spotify API. This is the curl command for it :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic M2...xMTJiNDc=" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "code=AQAXvqFp....29kd09" -d "redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback" https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

This works.

However,if I try to run it using python requests,I get a "invalid authorization" token error. I have reproduced the steps to get the auth token multiple times,but still same error.

I read on their GitHub that the auth code works only once,so I used the new auth code with python requests first,but still no luck. This is the python code:

```py
import requests as req
data = {
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'code':'AQAXvqFp........9kd09',
  'state': '34fFs29kd09=34fFs29kd09',
  'redirect_uri': 'https://example.com/callback'
}

header={
    "Authorization":f"Basic {authbasic}" #same as in the curl command
}
url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
response = req.post(url,headers=header,data=data)
print(response.content)
```

This is the error:

```
b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}'
```

How do I resolve this? I am using Python3.6

Comment: try `response = requests.post(url,headers=header, json=data)`

Comment: Now I am getting the html for a webpage that says "oops something went wrong"

Comment: Are you sure you can use the same authorization code multiple times?

Comment: No one code can be used only once. I got the auth code from the GET requests specified in theit documentation, and used it with the python code only. (One time use...that too with python)

Comment: Try using the requests.auth library for authentication. Make sure that the authentication type matches the one used by the spotify api. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/